# Displaying results properly

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to display a number of results but the code I have in place only displays one comment at a time instead of a number of them. How would I fix this?

Here's the code

```
  $page = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid1=$page LIMIT 10");
  $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   {
    //get data
   $nick1 = $runrows['name1'];
   $com1 = $runrows['comment1'];
   $date1 = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date1']));
   echo "";
?>
<?php echo $nick1; ?><br>
<?php echo $com1; ?><br>
<?php echo $date1; ?>
<br>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch all rows in result set you have to use loop something like below

```
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   echo $runrows['name1'];
   echo $runrows['comment1'];
   echo strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date1']));
   echo "";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you need all data:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid1=$page");
print mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

2) If you need data & use limit

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM comments WHERE commentid1=$page LIMIT 10");
print mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()'),0);
```

2) If you need not all data (only count of rows)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE commentid1=$page");
print mysql_result($sql,0);
```